# Simple jQuery AJAX request not working in Chrome (with error message)

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

Here is the AJAX method that works in Safari, but not in Chrome. Error message follows.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.infobutton').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://apps.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/services/mpconnect_service.cfm',
      data: {
        'mainSearchCriteria.v.cs': $(this).attr('data-code-system'),
        'mainSearchCriteria.v.c':  $(this).attr('data-code')
      },
      dataType: 'xml',
      async: false,
      method: 'GET',
      success: function(data){
        console.log('success');
        console.log(data);
      },
      done: function(data){
        console.log('done');
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(data){
        console.log('error');
        console.log(data.error());
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The console output gives the `statusText` in the `error` callback as this: `"Error: NetworkError: DOM Exception 19"`. [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMException) talks about DOM Exception 19, but that just says `NETWORK ERROR`. Not helpful.

I know from other research that Chrome has known issues with security, XSS, etc.

I've tried every suggestion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043376/jquery-ajax-ajax-not-working-on-chrome-please-help) SO post, as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110452/jquery-simple-ajax-request-not-working). No luck.

Going directly to the URL with that query string works. You can view it [here](http://apps2.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/services/mpconnect_service.cfm?mainSearchCriteria.v.cs=2.16.840.1.113883.6.103&mainSearchCriteria.v.c=493.22).

Also notice that this isn't part of an application. The html is literally just `<button class="infobutton">Click Me</button>`. This is just a proof of concept to get the AJAX working.

**UPDATE** 
I can also confirm that I get this same error both locally (using the `file:///` protocol), and remotely, working on a dev server.

Comment: Does the error occur only when launching the page locally from your system (file:///...), only online or both?

Comment: I've only tried it locally and on JSFiddle with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set `crossDomain: true`, and set up a Location redirect on your domain to point to the nih.gov URL.

One of the ways to get around the restriction is to start the request on a domain that is allowed by policy.  In other words, it has to be on the same domain as the JavaScript that is making the request.  Your page can then redirect the request to another domain.

**Local Page Example**

```
<?php
// http://yourdomain.com/some/url/redirect.php
header("Location: http://apps.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/services/mpconnect_service.cfm");
?>
```

Then, replace the URL in your JavaScript with `http://yourdomain.com/some/url/redirect.php`. The effect is circumvention of the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you clarify 'set up a location redirect on your domain'?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I'll edit in the details for location redirect.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your error handling use console.log(data.status)
2. Check your request URL - it returns 404 (not found)

Did you try Fiddler2 -great tool for debugging

Comment: I'm not sure how you're seeing the request URL return a 404. Returns a 200 for me.